# In magento,How to display all root categories in frontend?

Tags: magento

I have created n number of root categories in admin panel.
How to display all those root category in frontend page.can i get a file path where i have to change a code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//if you want only active categories
;
```

Comment: Thank u Qaisar,In which file i should edit this code?

Comment: which page u want to add this?

Comment: Can we show all the root categories in font end home page,i wanna show all root categories in front end home page